# Runtime issues with iOS 10/XCode 8

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios10, xcode8

Since I built and started running app on iOS 10 simulator, I started getting logs such as :

```
objc[6880]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x120275910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x12009f210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

2016-09-14 17:18:55.812525 MyApp[6880:340725] bundleid: com.MyApps.MyApp, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0

2016-09-14 17:18:55.813154 MyApp[6880:340725] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 17:18:55.842900 MyApp[6880:340837] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 17:18:55.843428 MyApp[6880:340837] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 17:18:55.855848 MyApp[6880:340836] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-14 17:18:55.870530 MyApp[6880:340725] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
```

Wonder how I fix them ? I never saw these on XCode 7.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have the same issue, but there is something you can do to,

1) Go in Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
2) Run Section on the left, select Argument Tab and in Environment Variable put this.

> OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to value : disable.

For more information please find the below screenshot.

[image]

This will get rid of messages in the console.

But I still struggle with the `PLBuildVersion` is implemented in both....

I hope this helps you !

*** EDIT ****
I found that the issue was caused by `Facebook SDK`. I removed the framework from `CocoaPods`, installed it manually by copying the SDK in my project folder and I have no errors now.

Comment: Hi @Adried Am trying to integrate fb login. am using XCode 8 GM. The issue is the facebook page unnable to redirect to the app after login. am stuck on this for two days kindly help me. Thank You

Answer (score -1):

check if your 
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:) 
in AppDelegate.swift is declared private, if yes, then remove the private keyword.
It should work after that.

Comment: Strange kludge and it doesn't work