# Updated to Xcode 8 and App is crashing on Launch

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode8, ios10, macos-sierra

Edit:

====================================================================

This may seem Duplicate at the First look but in all other questions they are treating this as Warning But in my case I am getting Crash at this Error and I have applied all the questions But yet not able to solve the issue.

====================================================================

I just installed Xcode 8 and also Updated my Mac to Sierra,
My xcode project contains cocoapods, I updated  the cocoapods,and then I opened my project in Xcode,

and at the first run App crashed at the launch time with following error.

> objc[7518]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode
>   8.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x1100ad910) and /Applications/Xcode
>   8.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x10fed7210).

**One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

What I found on Internet.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63254

Applied This  Also But no Success
[Runtime issues with iOS 10/XCode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491675/runtime-issues-with-ios-10-xcode-8)

Also Applied This But No Success
[Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks)

I was unable to find a way to get rid of the warning, but if you want to prevent the app from crashing, you need to provide a description for why you are accessing the camera, photo library, etc. This is new in iOS10.

Added following into your Info.plist file. But none are working.

Key:  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description Value:  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
Key:  Privacy - Camera Usage Description Value:  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

Please help Have to submit app next week, I am in a tight situation.

Comment: You may be using gallery to pick image. did you specify "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" in .plist ?

Comment: @Arasuvel  this may Look Duplicate from First Look but Please read my problem , I have applied all the solution they said in different question though I am not able to resolve my issue.

Comment: @Anand: did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry to say But Still struggling with the issue, due to urgency I rollback to Xcode 7.3.